# Text not showing in HTML file. Script tag possibly making Text disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image

I was trying to figure out how to get HTML to choose a new random image file everytime the page is reloaded, and i did manage to figure it out, but my problem is now that none of the text shows up at all how i want it to and the only thing that shows is the image. Weird thing is anything in style tag works.

Im assuming it has something to do with the script tag cuz when i remove it the text shows perfectly fine. I just want the text to appear how it normally would above and below the image.

PLEASE HELP and thanks. Im also new to HTML.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    Hello World <br>
</body> 
<br>

<body id ="img"  style ="border: 2px solid #6b1148;">
    <script src="rand.js"></script> <br>  
</body> 
<br>

<body>
    Goodbye World <br>
</body> 

</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var images = [
  '1.png',
  '2.png',
  '3.png',
]

var img = document.getElementById("img");

function imgDisp(num) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  img.style.content = 'url("' + images[num] +'")';

}
imgDisp();
```

I tried removing the script lines and the text shows fine but of course not the solution because i still want the image.

Comment: try `img.style.backgroundImage` - since, I believe you're trying to add a background image to the body

Comment: You have 3 body tags, there should only be one.

Comment: @Phix - and they don't want to set the `style.content` of any of them :p

Comment: I edited my comment again, some of the words didnt show up for some reason it should make a little bit more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When browser parses your html code, notice that there is only one body element. You can check this by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+I` and checking the Elements.

The reason why you aren't able to see your text above and below the image is because in your `rand.js` file, you are **changing the style of the entire body element**, thus replacing everything you've written with the random image.
You can avoid this by using a `<div>` tag where you have `id="img"`

Also make sure to have your script tag at the end of body.

Check this snippet I wrote from yours:

```js
var images = [
  'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/0e/f5/49/0ef5497a58c2ba5900ffa8a4656ed0a8.jpg',
  'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/3a/6b/b7/3a6bb70331903da7f58d9a6e7a6a5b2e.jpg',
  'https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/335/335293.png'
]
  
  var img = document.getElementById("img");
  
  function imgDisp(num) {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    img.style.content = 'url("' + images[num] +'")';
 
  }
  imgDisp();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <div id ="img"  style ="border: 2px solid #6b1148"></div>
    <p>Goodbye World</p>
    <script src="rand.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I see this answer answers your question with a working example. It would be cool if you could accept, or at least upvote.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you wanted to change the body background image with your script. So I changed the 'style.content' atributte to 'style.backgroundImage'.

I rewri your HTML because you can't have more than one  tag in a HTML file. I also put the text in a

tag, which stands for 'paragraph', we use this tag to write simple text in the HTML file.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body id="img" style="border: 2px solid #6b1148;">
    <script src="rand.js"></script> 

    <p>Hello World</p>
    <br>

    <p>Goodbye World </p>
    <br>

</body> 

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var images = [
    '1.png',
    '2.png',
    '3.png',
]
  
var img = document.getElementById("img");
  
function imgDisp(num) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + images[num] +'")';
  
}
imgDisp();
```

I hope I can help you bro! Happy New Year! HTML and JS is a good way to start learning to code, you are going in a good path. Sorry if there is any English errors in this, I am a brazillian trying to help haha.